# Trying to extract version info and save to INI file on Windows 11 with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am not familiar with PowerShell and I am struggling at the outset.

My task I want to achieve:

1. Get version number from EXE file.

I know I can get that:

```
(Get-Item "MeetSchedAssistSetup.exe").VersionInfo.ProductVersionRaw
```

In the console window it displays:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
23     0      3      0
```

2. Open a INI file. I installed the `PSIni` module but this line fails:

```
$ini = Get-IniContent version_meetschedassist2.ini
```

It says:

```
Get-IniContent : The 'Get-IniContent' command was found in the module 'PsIni', but the module could not be loaded. For
more information, run 'Import-Module PsIni'.
At line:1 char:8
+ $ini = Get-IniContent version_meetschedassist2.ini
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-IniContent:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule
```

How do I load the INI?

My task it to update this bit in the INI:

```
[MeetSchedAssist Update]
LatestVersion=23.03
LatestVersionString=23.0.3
```

So I want to:

- Open INI
- Extract Version from EXE
- Update the two INI values from the Version
- Save INI

I tried using `Import-Module`:

```
Import-Module : File C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PsIni\3.1.3\PsIni.psm1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on
this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module PsIni
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [Import-Module], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

No joy.

Comment: Set your execution policy accordingly.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala So we need to set the execution policy for this session only ... Ok ...

Comment: Wanted to follow up. Did setting the execution policy accordingly resolve your issue?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I can't work out how do to it. Thanks for asking.

Comment: It's based on your environment on what is, and isn't allowed. You'll have to look into [Execution Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-5.1), for what your needs are. Something like `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope CurrentUser`. Mine is set to `Unrestricted` allowing all scripts to be ran.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Thanks. What about "current session" ?

Comment: You can always just set it back to `restricted` at the end of the script if that helps. Closest you'll get to just that session is setting the policy scope for the current user, and just reverting when done.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala It does work. Thanks. Now I have to workout how to do the rest.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I can ge current values in the INI, eg: `$ini["MeetSchedAssist Update"]["LatestVersion"]`. But, how do I go from `(Get-Item "MeetSchedAssistSetup.exe").VersionInfo.ProductVersionRaw` to those to formats?

Comment: To summarize, you want to update/replace the ini file contents in `version_meetschedassist2.ini`, with the versions produced by `(Get-Item "MeetSchedAssistSetup.exe").VersionInfo.ProductVersionRaw`? You're just unsure how to save it back to the ini file, or with replacing the content?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I want to take the version info from my exe, and UPDATE those two values in the INI. The string needs to be x.x.x (so it loses the 4th part of the version, and drops leading zeroes. And the other value is the equivalent as a floating number. So, 23.0.3.0 becomes 23.0.3 (string version) and 23.03 (numeric version). Once those two values are updated it can save the INi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very quick and *very* dirty way of doing this just as an example:

```
$exe_info = Get-Item -Path '.\MeetSchedAssistSetup.exe'
$ini_path = '.\version_meetschedassist2.ini'
$ini = Get-IniContent -FilePath $ini_path

$ini['MeetSchedAssist Update']['LatestVersion'] = 
    '{0}.{1}{2}' -f $exe_info.VersionInfo.FileMajorPart, 
                    $exe_info.VersionInfo.FileMinorPart, $exe_info.VersionInfo.FileBuildPart
$ini['MeetSchedAssist Update']['LatestVersionString'] =
    '{0}.{1}.{2}' -f $exe_info.VersionInfo.FileMajorPart, 
                    $exe_info.VersionInfo.FileMinorPart, $exe_info.VersionInfo.FileBuildPart

Out-IniFile -FilePath $ini_path -InputObject $ini -Force
```

Since `Get-IniContent` gets saved into memory via `$ini`, you can replace the values with what you need them to be and pass it back out with `Out-IniFile` specifying `$ini` as the `-InputObject` for it. The values are updated using string concatenating of the version info.

Comment: Thank you. I’ll give this a try tomorrow!